# ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000 error when running "axe http://localhost:9000" command

Tags: npm, vuejs3, uiaccessibility, axe

Currently, I have a requirement to add accessibility testing on GitHub CI action so that every pull request it can be validated. After doing some research, I came to know that we can add below command.

```
      npm install -g @axe-core/cli
      axe http://localhost:9000 --exit
```

However,  I am encountering below error when ci action run.

**Error:** fetchError: request to http://localhost:9000 failed, reason: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9000

I have tried few options to solve this issue but no success. Tried to change the port, run the command in vs terminal but having same issue.

Can anyone please help me on this ? Please note, I am using it in vue3 application.

Comment: Hi @TechGig, if you are getting a connection refused, it is likely something to do with the web server that is running during the CI process. Can you Curl it and get a response? For instance, I am *not* running a web server, so I get a connection refused for that reason: `curl http://localhost:9000`  yeilds `curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 9000 after 9 ms: Connection refused`